# Ler XML recebido do ajax - PHP

Tags: php, ajax, xml

No php usando o comando `var_dump($_FILES ['filexml']);` recebo os seguintes valores do ajax

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(56) "nomeficticio.xml"
  ["type"]=>
  string(8) "text/xml"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpoqnomeficticio"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(16536)
}
```

Através desses dados, como eu posso ler esse arquivo XML? com PHP
eu até tentei usar o comando `simplexml_load_file($_FILES['filexml']);` mas deu o seguinte erro:

> simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array
>   given

Comment: Você está passando o array inteiro como parâmetro, enquanto você precisa do caminho de um arquivo para fazer a leitura. Acho que, no seu caso, `simplexml_load_file($_FILES['filexml']['name'])` seja o mais adequado, contanto que o caminho nesse campo do array seja o correto

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira hmmm, eu preciso primeiro fazer o upload para depois poder ler o XML? ou eu posso ler o xml sem necessariamente fazer o upload dele(salvar em algum diretório)

Comment: A galera já acertou no pulo aí, hahaha. Mas o lance era mais ou menos esse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O array já diz onde o arquivo está localizado. Basta abri-lo:

```
simplexml_load_file($_FILES['filexml']['tmp_name']);
```

Porém, não é recomendável tratar um arquivo que está em um diretório temporário, já que o próprio OS pode limpar esse diretório de tempos em tempos. Prefira movê-lo antes disso:

```
$basename = basename($_FILES['filexml']['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filexml']['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . $basename);
simplexml_load_file( __DIR__ . $basename);
```

Comment: Simmm, isso mesmo
Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: As duas resposta foram ótimas, mas essa daqui me respondeu também uma outra pequena dúvida que tinha [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86190/ler-xml-recebido-do-ajax-php#comment173583_86190)

Answer (score 3):

Você só precisa usar o 'tmp_name' no lugar de 'name'. 
Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['input_file'])){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['input_file']["tmp_name"]);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($xml);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
<form class="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="file" name="input_file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Caso dê certo, ficaria feliz se me der upvote e escolher a minha resposta.

Comment: Simmm, isso mesmo
Funcionou perfeitamente.